# Python request to crawl URL returns 404 Error while working inside the browser

Tags: python, request, web-crawler

I have a crawling python script that hangs on a url: `pulsepoint.com/sellers.json`

The bot uses a standard request to get the content, but is returned Error 404. In the browser it works (there is a 301 redirect, but request can follow that). My first hunch is that this could be a request header issue, so I copied my browser configuration. The code looks like this

```
        crawled_url="pulsepoint.com"
        seller_json_url = 'http://{thehost}/sellers.json'.format(thehost=crawled_url)
        print(seller_json_url)
        myheaders = {
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0',
                'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
                'Accept-Language': 'fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
                'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
                'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                'Pragma': 'no-cache',
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
            }
        r = requests.get(seller_json_url, headers=myheaders)
        logging.info("  %d" % r.status_code)
```

But I am still getting a 404 Error.

My next guess:

- Login? Not used here
- Cookies? Not that I can see

So how is their server blocking my bot? This is an URL that is supposed to be crawled by the way, nothing illegal..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do a workaround on the SSL certificate error like below:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import ssl
import json

#this is a workaround on the SSL error
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
crawled_url="pulsepoint.com"
seller_json_url = 'http://{thehost}/sellers.json'.format(thehost=crawled_url)
print(seller_json_url)

response = urlopen(seller_json_url).read() 
# print in dictionary format
print(json.loads(response))
```

Sample response:

{'contact_email': 'PublisherSupport@pulsepoint.com', 'contact_address': '360 Madison Ave, 14th Floor, NY, NY, 10017', 'version': '1.0', 'identifiers': [{'name': 'TAG-ID', 'value': '89ff185a4c4e857c'}], 'sellers': [{'seller_id': '508738', ...

...'seller_type': 'PUBLISHER'}, {'seller_id': '562225', 'name': 'EL DIARIO', 'domain': 'impremedia.com', 'seller_type': 'PUBLISHER'}]}

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Your code works, but need to have the redirected url,not the original URL. I have a few URL with redirects that work just fine, I can't understand why this one would need to have the other domain hardcoded..

Comment: Sorry about using the redirected url.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks that made it! I had to work a bit on the solution because of some varying level of respect of my headers amongst urls, but your answer is the right one. I'll add one as a complement!

Answer (score 1):

You can just go directly to the link and extract the data, no need to get 301 to the correct link

```
import requests
headers = {"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1"}
response = requests.get(
    url="https://projects.contextweb.com/sellersjson/sellers.json",
    headers=headers,
    verify=False,
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I have a couple hundred url, some have a sellers.json register, some don't, and a few are using redirection. So I would like to have a robust crawler that fits most situations..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just for other people, an hardened version of âńōŋŷXmoůŜ's answer, because:

- Some website want headers to answer;
- Some website use weird encoding
- Some website send gzipped answer when not requested.

```
    import urllib
    import ssl
    import json
    from io import BytesIO
    import gzip

    ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
    crawled_url="pulsepoint.com"
    seller_json_url = 'http://{thehost}/sellers.json'.format(thehost=crawled_url)
    req = urllib.request.Request(seller_json_url)
    # ADDING THE HEADERS
    req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0')
    req.add_header('Accept','application/json,text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8')

    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    data=response.read()
    # IN CASE THE ANSWER IS GZIPPED
    if response.info().get('Content-Encoding') == 'gzip':
        buf = BytesIO(data)
        f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buf)
        data = f.read()
    # ADAPTS THE ENCODING TO THE ANSWER
    print(json.loads(data.decode(response.info().get_param('charset') or 'utf-8')))
```

Thanks again!